# Why is it that panic!(_) can be returned with or without a ;?

Tags: rust, panic

Looking at question number 3 [here](https://practice.rs/basic-types/functions.html).

As an example, I've edited as such.

```
fn main() {
    never_return();
    // println!("Failed!");
}

fn never_return() -> ! {
    // Implement this function, don't modify the fn signatures
    panic!("stop")
}
```

The expectation when returning something from a fn is without a trailing `;`. In the above case, the `panic!(_)` returns a type `never` and does what I would expect it to. However, the same fn signature, returning `!`, compiles to the same regardless of whether there is a `;` after the `panic` macro or not. I'm assuming this is the case because of the intrinsics of a `panic`? But couldn't find a technical explanation to it that I understood.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding the `!` type.
The `panic!` macro does not "return a type never", rather it **never returns**.
By using a `fn foo() -> !` signature, you're declaring that this function never actually returns, and invoking another function/macro that never returns satisfies that.
Similarly, the following compiles:

```rust
fn never_returns() -> ! {
  loop { }
}
```

since it loops forever, it *never* returns